# Constructing a else statement if none of the check boxes are checked

Tags: javascript

So I figured out how to create a script that gets all the related check box values and insert it into an alert prompt box so far everything thing works amazingly so I 
have this problem that I am facing currently so when you click on any of the check

boxes it shows the check boxes values that you selected after you click on the get button in the alert popup box for example ***I love etc...*** so I notice when I don't click on any of the check boxes it will say ***I love*** so I want

to insert a else statement if no checks boxes are selected then it will say please select one or more check boxes. The problem I am facing is that I don't know where to put this else statement at or how to structure it correctly. I tried to put it into the for loop section but

it generated it multiple times I just want the 
else to be mentioned one time meaning not in the same amount of times as the loop. Here is my code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.querySelector('#get-sport-check-box-values').addEventListener('click', getOfffered_Service);

  function getOfffered_Service() {
    var chks = document.querySelectorAll(".form input[name='sport']");

    var text = new Array();
    var strtext = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
      if (chks[i].checked) {

        var arlength = text.length;
        text[arlength] = chks[i].value;
      }

      /*Where? And how correctly? 
      else{
      alert('please select one or more check boxes')
      }*/

    }

    strtext = text.join(' and ');
    alert('I love ' + strtext);
  }

});
```

```css
.sport-check-value-label {
  display: inline;
}

#get-sport-check-box-values {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>What sports do you like?</h3>

<div class='form'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='basketball'>
  <p class='sport-check-value-label'>Basketball</p><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='baseball'>
  <p class='sport-check-value-label'>Baseball</p><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='football'>
  <p class='sport-check-value-label'>Football</p><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='mma'>
  <p class='sport-check-value-label'>MMA</p>

  <button id='get-sport-check-box-values'>Get</button>
</div>
<!--</form>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a if else statement structure.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

document.querySelector('#get-sport-check-box-values').addEventListener('click',getOfffered_Service);

function getOfffered_Service(){
var chks = document.querySelectorAll(".form input[name='sport']");
  
var text = new Array();
var strtext = '';
 
for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++){
if (chks[i].checked){

var arlength = text.length;
text[arlength] = chks[i].value;
}
 
}
strtext = text.join(' and ');

/*<Check boxes are checked>*/
if(strtext){
alert('I love ' + strtext);
}
/*</Check boxes are checked>*/

/*<Check boxes are not checked>*/
else{
alert('please select one or more check boxes');
}
/*</Check boxes are not checked>*/

}

});
```

```css
.sport-check-value-label{
  display: inline;
}

#get-sport-check-box-values{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>What sports do you like?</h3>

<div class='form'>
<input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='basketball'><p class='sport-check-value-label'>Basketball</p><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='baseball'><p class='sport-check-value-label'>Baseball</p><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='football'><p class='sport-check-value-label'>Football</p><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='mma'><p class='sport-check-value-label'>MMA</p>

<button id='get-sport-check-box-values'>Get</button>
</div>
<!--</form>-->
```

Comment: Thanks every one for trying to help me out but I got to grant fsofb as the best answer his method seems more what I was looking for.  Thank you fsofb,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:checked` psuedo-selector and `alert` / `return` early if the length of the resulting `NodeList` (the checked checkboxes) is 0:

```js
document.querySelector('#get-sport-check-box-values').addEventListener('click', getOfffered_Service);

function getOfffered_Service() {
  var chks = document.querySelectorAll(".form input[name='sport']:checked");
  if (chks.length === 0) return alert('please select one or more check boxes');
  const strtext = [...chks]
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value)
    .join(' and ');
  alert('I love ' + strtext);
}
```

```css
.sport-check-value-label {
  display: inline;
}

#get-sport-check-box-values {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>What sports do you like?</h3>

<div class='form'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='basketball'>
  <p class='sport-check-value-label'>Basketball</p><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='baseball'>
  <p class='sport-check-value-label'>Baseball</p><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='football'>
  <p class='sport-check-value-label'>Football</p><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='sport' value='mma'>
  <p class='sport-check-value-label'>MMA</p>

  <button id='get-sport-check-box-values'>Get</button>
</div>
<!--</form>-->
```